# Extract yaml file from a variable within a yaml file

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I have a simple yaml file:

```
# replicas: number of pods
replicas: 1
# test
hello: world
```

I am storing this inside a kubernetes config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  helm_values: |
    # replicas: number of pods
    replicas: 1
    # test
    hello: world
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-07-30T06:07:38Z
```

I now want to extract the inner yaml file from the configmap. Trying [yq](https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I get:

```
$ VAR=$(oc get configmap backoffice-deployer -o yaml | yq .data.helm_values)
$ echo $VAR
"# replicas: number of pods\nreplicas: 1\n# test\nhello: world\n"
```

If I try to echo or printf the VAR into a file it isn't nicely formatted like the original file.

Whats the simplest way in bash to get the extracted data back in the format of the original file in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your code exactly, but here's what I'm getting (OSX, bash v4.4.23, yq v2.1.0):

```
var=$(cat test.yaml | yq r - data.helm_values)
echo "$var"
```

with output

```
# replicas: number of pods
replicas: 1
# test
hello: world
```

If I forget the quotes, (`echo $var`), then:

```
# replicas: number of pods replicas: 1 # test hello: world
```

(no line breaks, no `\n`).

I can even further process it:

```
echo "$var" | yq r - hello
# => world
```

With yq v2.6.0 the command arguments have changed:

```
var=$(cat test.yaml | yq -r .data.helm_values)
echo "$var"
```

Comment: For `cat test.yaml | yq r - data.helm_values` I get `yq: error: argument files: can't open 'data.helm_values': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` using `yq 2.6.0`.

Comment: aha brew has `2.1.0` but i have picked up `2.6.0`. i am targetting linux so i am not sure that using an older version is the way to go.

Comment: i have added an edit with the parameters for v2.6.0. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the main point was how to use `$var` in `bash`. I did not know what `jq` version you were working on, just that its syntax didn't work for me :p Thanks.